# How do I get the second id from the url?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-9

There is a product that has a category.
The path to the categories looks like this:

```
Route::get('/catalog/{category}', [MainController::class, 'categoryFilter']);
```

There is also another product, the path to which I want to organize through the category id and the product id, and it looks like this:

```
Route::get('/catalog/{category}/{product}', [ProductController::class, 'productPage']);
```

When you go to the product page, the url bar has both the category id and the product.
But when I want to get data about a product through its id or `{product}`, I get only the id of the category:

```
public function productPage($product){
       $$current Product = Product::find($product);
       return view('product', compact('current Product'));
}
```

How do I get the product id and not the category?

I tried to get the product id in the function via `$id`.
I know that there is a way to get the product through the model, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

okay, i have to write function just like that

```
public function productPage($category, $product){
       $current Product = Product::find($product);
       return view('product', compact('current Product'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the product id in the `productPage()` function, you need to update the method signature to accept both category and product as parameters, like this:

```
public function productPage($category, $product){
    $currentProduct = Product::find($product);
    return view('product', compact('currentProduct'));
}
```